# Angularjs route with unchanged data, avoid re-rendering templates for controllers for that route?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service, angularjs-routing

If I am changing a route, and the data for that route has not changed, can I avoid re-rendering my templates for the controllers for that route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks Stu.  I don't think I need ui-router.  I think my question was not simple enough (I simplified it just now) - sorry about that, and thanks again for your answer.

I actually can just use the reload on search feature.  This does require me to change my urls, which isn't ideal, but it's an acceptable compromise to get what I want easily:

See: [Can you change a path without reloading the controller in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14974271/can-you-change-a-path-without-reloading-the-controller-in-angularjs)

Answer (score 0):

> 1) If I am changing a route, and the data for that route has not changed, can I avoid re-rendering my templates for the controllers for that route?

I can't follow all of the details of your use case entirely, but you might want to look at [ui-router](http://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router).  You can have nested states (glorified routes) and multiple views (templates) per state, which might help you to avoid reloading portions of the page.