# UI-Router hide parent template

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

Suppose a state called **projects.new** where **new** is a nested state of **projects**.
Is there a way to hide the parent's template to show only child template?

Comment: I was looking for the same, and this answer helped me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21696104/how-to-ng-hide-and-ng-show-views-using-angular-ui-router

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30876130/hiding-parent-state-view-from-child-state-view-in-angularjs-best-practices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check when the state (route) change and hide parent view. [Demo in jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/auxcoder/neo5cL34/). This working example use [AngularUI Router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) but the logic is pretty much the same with the standard ngRoute.

```
var parents = ['parent'];
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(event, toState) {
    $scope.hideParent = parents.indexOf(toState.name) !== -1 ? false : true;
});
```

Or we can checking if the state name contains the parent state name. A simple regex pattern can tell us, state names use dot notation to delimit `parent.child`.

```
var re = /^projects.\w+/;
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(event, toState) {
    $scope.hideParent = re.test(toState.name);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to solve this problem.

## Addressing the ui view by name

You could either use the named views to declare that your template should be rendered in the correct "parent" ui view by addressing the view by name like done here:

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views

This requires either providing named `ui-view` elements or addressing them by referencing a known grandparent state.

## Using a different state hierarchy

Another option is to not have these states inherit from each other (or at least having the `.new` not being a child of the `projects` list state. By using a dot in the name, you introduce a substate of the state before the dot. So there are several options:

- calling the states `projects` and `projects_new` make them appear on the same level and thus not trying to render the `new` part into the list template. (i don't like this approach that much because there is something in common between those states)
- introducing an abstract state and moving the current "project list" state under this, so that you have `projects` abstract with two substates `projects.list` and `projects.new` where `projects.list` just uses the url of the parent state. For details please have a look at the great docs at https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views#abstract-state-usage-examples