# ng-show with $state.includes has blink/flickering - angular; ui-router

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-ui-router, ng-show, angular-ui-router-extras

As described here [How to ng-hide and ng-show views using angular ui router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21696104/how-to-ng-hide-and-ng-show-views-using-angular-ui-router), I have the following markup:

```
<div class='container'>
  <div ng-show='$state.includes('state1')></div>
  <div ng-show='$state.includes('state2')></div>
</div>
```

Using flex-box in css:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

Now it when I switch between the two states both divs are displayed for a blink of an eye resulting in an ugly blink effect.

I tried ng-cloak from [Angularjs - ng-cloak/ng-show elements blink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11249768/angularjs-ng-cloak-ng-show-elements-blink#13276214), but without any success.

I can't use ng-if since I use 'Sticky State' from [ui-router-extras](https://github.com/christopherthielen/ui-router-extras), which requires the DOM to persist.

Comment: Have you tried animating `ng-show` with `ng-animate`? ex. `.ng-hide-add        { animation:0.5s showdiv ease; } .ng-hide-remove  { animation:0.5s hideDiv ease; }`

Comment: Use an alternate css class to hide by default. `<div class="default-hide" ng-show="$state.includes('state1')}"></div>`. Where default-hide should have a `display: none` avoid `!important`.

Comment: The hide-add is delayed, but the hide-remove is not. When I set the time to 2seconds or so, as a result the blink turns into a long blink. It shows a nice solution, but by delaying hide-remove and not hide-add. Only I can't get this to work..

Comment: @MiguelLattuada with default-hide it doesn't show up at all. I think about trying it with adding a class with ng-class on $state.includes(). It just seems like rebuilding ng-show..

Comment: Did you ever find the issue?

Answer (score 0):

`$state` won't be available to use in HTML so

1) you can do something like this in Ctrl

```
$scope.state = $state;
```

but i won't recommend this

2) In HTML

```
<div class='container'>
  <div ng-show="showThis('state1')"></div>
  <div ng-show="showThis('state2')"></div>
</div>
```

In Controller

```
$scope.showThis = function(type){
  return $state.includes(type);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast response. I use your first option. In option 2 the problem remains.

Answer (score 0):

Even though you already mentioned that you have tried ng-cloak, I think that the right answer to your issue is indeed ng-cloak with the:

```
[ng\:cloak], [ng-cloak], .ng-cloak {
    display: none !important;
}
```

style configuration. [I have made an example on CodePen.io that show exaclty this solution working with Angular UI Router.](http://codepen.io/bruno_krebs/pen/bBrKMj?editors=1010) As you can see in the example, the whole view blinks as you mentioned but, if you add the 'ng-cloak' directive to the:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
```

which will then become:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-cloak>
```

you will see that [Angular protects the view from being showed (blinking).](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak) And that is exactly the purpose of the of the 'ng-cloak' directive.

Hope this example help you solving you issue.

Comment: Thanks for the CodePen. Sadly it doesn't work. I also dont see any flicker when I remove ng-cloak in the Pen..

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-style to remove the flicker effect.

```
<div class='container'>
    <div ng-style="{'display': $state.includes('state1') ? 'block' : 'none'}"></div>
    <div ng-style="{'display': $state.includes('state2') ? 'block' : 'none'}"></div>
</div>
```

I'm not sure why ng-show triggers a flicker effect with sticky states, but this workaround fixes the issue.