# Change the URL without changing view and controller AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

In my AngularJS project, I have a form having searching filter. What I do is I can select filters and then click on Search button. It gives me a list of search results. From that search result, I have a button from which I can navigate to another page. Now if I click on "Browser back button", it reloads the first page completely without having my search results- just like a fresh reload of page.

Is there any way so I can change the URL of first page along with query string when I click on Search button and be there on the same page without changing the controller and view ?

Here is my piece of code:

View page:

```
<div>
    <select class="form-control" ng-options="producttype.Name></select>

</div>
<div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="search()">
       Search
    </button>
</div>
```

In Controller:

```
$scope.search = function () {
    // Search method to get results
}
```

The page's url is #/Product.
Config page is :

```
app.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/Product',
        {
            controller: 'ProductController',
            templateUrl: '/app/product.html'
        })
```

I want to make it change to #/Product?ProductType=".." when user click on Search button on the same page. 
I referred [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18337093/updating-url-in-angular-js-without-re-rendering-view) and [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14974271/can-you-change-a-path-without-reloading-the-controller-in-angularjs) but did not get it. 
Any suggestions how can I achieve this ? 
Thanks.

Comment: When you start on the search page you want the url = #/Product. But, when you go to the search results page you want the url to contain the query params, ie: #/Product?ProductType=xyz. BUT, you want to maintain the same controller & view? Correct?

Comment: @whyceewhite Exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
app.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/Product',
        {
            controller: 'ProductController',
            templateUrl: '/app/product.html',
            reloadOnSearch: false
        });
```

and then in controller

```
$scope.search = function () {
    // Search method to get results
    ...
    //and after getting results
    $location.search('ProductType', someProductType);
}
```

did you try this ?

**UPDATE**
in order to match your url string with view through navigation and etc ,you need to inject *$routeParams* in controller

### SomeCtrl.js

```
window.app.controller('SomeCtrl', ['$scope',  '$routeParams', '$location', 'SomeResourceOrService' ,
        function ($scope, $routeParams, $location, SomeResourceOrService) {
          //check if filter allready setup
          if (IsSearchFilterSetUp($routeParams))
          {
              //search and update
              SomeResourceOrService.Search({ProductType:$routeParams.ProductType},function(data)
              {
                  $scope.Products=data;
              };
          }  
          ...
```

and in your case *IsSearchFilterSetUp* function will be look something like this

```
 function IsSearchFilterSetUp(routeparmas)
        {
            return routeparmas.ProductType!='';
        }
```

and resourse something like this

### SomeResourceOrService.js

```
 window.app.factory('SomeResourceOrService',
            ['$resource',
                function ($resource) {
                   return $resource('', {},
                        {
                            Search: { method: 'GET', isArray: true, url: 'someurl' },
                            
                        }
                    );
          }]);
```

Comment: It changed the url but when I click on link, it goes to next page. Now when I click on browser back button, i got the desired url (/products?ProductType=2) but I lost the search result. How can I get the results as well ?

Comment: one way to acheive this is inject '$routeParams' in conroller and on initialization of contoller check search params and if it is allready set in '$routeParams'  perform search with updating of view

Comment: Thank you for your help. But I have a que. Which search and update method should I write inside if condition ? Also where  do I need to define IsSearchFilterSetup method ?

Comment: please check the update,you can define IsSearchFilterSetup anywhere ,inside the controller definition for example