# Open Modal and change URL without change the view in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to open a modal with angularjs.

My route to task list is:

```
/client/:id/task/list
```

Its working fine. 
Now, i'm trying to show the task info in a modal, above the list.

My route for this is:

```
/client/:id/task/:id
```

How can i open the modal above the list view, change the URL, but don't change the view?

I saw a lot of topics about this, but with none solution.

Thanks.

Comment: a very basic question : you using ng-route or ui-router?

Comment: are you using library such as bootstrap, jquery, etc. that offer modal dialogs. if so you can make a GET or POST request to that route and populate the dialog with the response

Comment: i'm using ui-router. 
@YoelNunez, i have all the data for modal dialog, my problem is show the modal without change the content, just put the modal above the view and change the url.

Comment: try looking at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14974271/can-you-change-a-path-without-reloading-the-controller-in-angularjs) specifically at the part that has to do with "reloadOnSearch"

Comment: @YoelNunez, this is an option, the url will not be like /client/1/task/1, but like /client/1/task?taskId=1

This is my first option now if i can't find another one.

Comment: Why don't you use `/client/:id/task/` for the list state, that way you can then have the `/client/:id/task/:id` be a sub state

Comment: @JoseM, you're right. Because the /list, the modal wasn't working. I changed and now is working above the content. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify states you want to show as modal and when handled, return to state you want to. For example;

```
app.config(function ($stateProvider) {      
  $stateProvider.state('tasks', {
    url: '/tasks',
    templateUrl: 'tasks.html',
    controller: 'TasksCtrl'

  }).state("tasks.show", {
    url: "/tasks/:id",
    onEnter: function($stateParams, $state, $modal) {
      $modal.open({
        templateUrl: "show.html",
        resolve: {},
        controller: function($scope, $state) {
          $scope.ok = function () {
            $scope.$close();
          };              
          $scope.dismiss = function () {
            $scope.$dismiss();
          };
        }
      }).result.then(function (result) { 
         // $scope.$close
      }, function (result) { 
         // $scope.$dismiss
      }).finally(function () { 
        // finally
        return $state.transitionTo("tasks");
      });
    }
  });
});
```

---

**Related** plunker here http://plnkr.co/edit/fCyrlH

[image: imgur]

Comment: Your answer was awesome! Very simple to understand! Thanks!
One question, I can't back the state, the result.then don't fire any time. Do you know why?

Comment: Actually, the callback success in result.then doensn't dispatch anything, but the second parameter dispatch.

result.then(successCallback, errorBack).

Comment: Edited the plunker. I added success/dismissed/finally handlers and some comments for clarity.