# Changing URL without reloading (angularjs // follow up Q.)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Im trying to change the url with angular without reloading the page.

I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14974271/can-you-change-a-path-without-reloading-the-controller-in-angularjs) and specifically this answer:

> If you need to change the path, add this after your .config in your
>   app file. Then you can do `$location.path('/sampleurl', false);` to
>   prevent reloading
>
> ```
> app.run(['$route', '$rootScope', '$location', function ($route, $rootScope, $location) {
>     var original = $location.path;
>     $location.path = function (path, reload) {
>         if (reload === false) {
>             var lastRoute = $route.current;
>             var un = $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function () {
>                 $route.current = lastRoute;
>                 un();
>             });
>         }
>         return original.apply($location, [path]);
>     };
> }])
> ```

However when i run that code i get an error straight away and console reads.

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr]  http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.2/$injector/unpr?p0=%24routeProvider%20%3C-%20%24route

When i click the link i read that maybe the error is because you cant pass $rootScope to anything but a directive or controller? Can someone help me explain whats going on?

Comment: Have you installed ngRoute? Also show your `config()`

Comment: Read [AngularJS Developer Guide - Using $location](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location).

Comment: @sbaaaang omg duh! thanks man, post that as a answer, the original questions answer never said it was using ngRoute and i didnt notice from the $route service.. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You did not installed `ngRoute` :)