# when clicking on a link -> go to different tab without reloading the page

Tags: angularjs

```
<a href="##webinar" onclick="location.reload();">goTOWebinarTab</a>
```

I'm using the code to go to the respective tab in the same page(angular tabs), and it is working fine only with the page reload is there a way I can do it without reloading the page.

> actual URL=/adv/about/research/
>       target URL=/adv/about/research/##webinar

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you change a path without reloading the controller in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14974271/can-you-change-a-path-without-reloading-the-controller-in-angularjs)

Answer (score 1):

Remove `onclick="location.reload();"`

and use href only

```
<a href="##webinar" >goTOWebinarTab</a>
```

because The reload() method is used to reload the current document.

Comment: Yes, but the href location(same page different tab) is working only with the reload. i'm looking something like without reload of page