# How to change URL while opening a fancybox and revert back URL when closed this fancybox using in angular cli?

Tags: angularjs, fancybox

I am looking to change the URL whenever fancybox is opened and the URL should get back to its original after closing the fancybox. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you ask more specific question? e.g., what causes you a problem? fancybox provides plenty of callbacks that you can use - https://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/docs/#events

Comment: Thanks for your reply...! Janis, actually everything is going fine in my angular project except that I want to add something in my URL, whenever a Fancybox is open for gallery images. And when I close that Fancybox the URL should get back to its previous state.

Comment: Are you using ui-router or ngRouter? And what does angular cli have to do with this?

Comment: @Protozoid ngRouter is using.

Comment: Maybe this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14974271/can-you-change-a-path-without-reloading-the-controller-in-angularjs