# Set $location in AngularJS / Electron app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, navigation, electron

Is it possible to change the URL for `$location` in AngularJS within an Electon app but without implicitly loading that URL? The problem is that Electron is loading `index.html` (and other resources) locally, which is intended. But then of course it also sets `$location` to the local file system.

**Background:** The reason why I need `$location` to point to the server is that there is some  existing legacy code (which I must not change) and this code uses e.g. `$location.search`. So after the Electron app has started I'd need to set the location correctly, so that this legacy code can work.

**UPDATE 17.07.2020**

Here is the requested example code:

I'm trying to set the location with `window.location = "https://example.com?param1=test"` so that the AngularJS function `$location.search()` returns `param1=test`. The problem is, as mentioned above, that when setting `window.location`, Electron loads the index.html from that server and replaces the content of the `BrowserWindow`. But I want to load those resources (index.html, *.js, *.css locally) I also tried:

```
window.location.href = ...
window.location.assign (...)
window.location.replace (...)
```

but all of these are reloading the page as well.

Comment: Some code examples of what you are trying to do and what you have done will help and is recommended.

Comment: Thanks @Zac! Just added an update to the initial post.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll want to add an event listener for `will-navigate`. Docs can be found [here](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/web-contents#event-will-navigate). The important piece:

> [The `will-event` event will be] emitted when a user or the page wants to start navigation. It can happen when the window.location object is changed or a user clicks a link in the page.

I'd imagine your **main.js** file will look something like this, it's bare-bones but I hope you get the idea.

```js
const {
  app
} = require("electron");

let window;
function createWindow(){
    window = new BrowserWindow(){...};
    // etc....
}

app.on("ready", createWindow);

// For all BrowserWindows you make, the inner bindings will be applied to each;
// more information for "web-contents-created" is here: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/app#event-web-contents-created
app.on("web-contents-created", (event, contents) => {
    contents.on("will-redirect", (event, navigationUrl) => {

        // prevent the window from changing path via "window.location = '....'"
        event.preventDefault();
        return;
    });
});
```

**FYI**: This event listener is [mainly used for security reasons](https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/security#12-disable-or-limit-navigation), but I don't see why you can't use it in your case.

Comment: Thanks Zac! Just tried it, but the inner 'will-redirect' is never triggered. Also if I do it like this: 'win.webContents.on("will-redirect", (event, navigationUrl) => {...}' (I mean without the encasing 'web-contents-created') it is not triggered. Instead when using 'will-navigate', indeed event.preventDefault() works (I tried that already in the past), but then also window.location is not set to the new URL.

Comment: @Bernd Hm, two suggestions then. In your electron app, you need to make a route for every single possible path you may have, ie. https://github.com/reZach/secure-electron-template/blob/master/app/src/core/routes.jsx. Otherwise, you need to change your angular app to always exist at a single url, but parameters you need to change, you will need to put them as hash parameters in your url (https://stackoverflow.com/a/14974448/1837080)

Comment: I don't know if I understand your suggestion correctly. In my app there is currently only a single route which displays the main page. The legacy code which I talked about, is doing multiple AJAX requests to different routes (to an external server), but that's not a problem, because I can rewrite the URLs by catching the ````onBeforeRequest````. The problem is that the legacy code needs the window.location object to point to the external server. But as said, I can't set it to that server, because then the Electron BrowserWindow is immediately replaced with the server content.

Comment: Ah, I think I understand more now. You likely need to re-write your front-end app, either to not use window.location, or perhaps pass in hash parameters (so that the page doesn't reload)